# Thought experiment on boundary condition of galaxies

Tags: general-relativity, galaxy-rotation-curve, asymptotics

A thought experiment: Let's assume that there is only *one single* galaxy in the whole universe.
How would it look like regarding the curvature of spacetime?

1. Would the spacetime be flat in the infinity (asymptotical flatness) or
2. would the spacetime vanish in the infinity, becoming more and more "thinner" (The opposite of what happens *nearer* the centre of gravity)?

**If 1 or 2 is right, how can we see this from our universe with so many galaxies?**

**And if 1 or 2 is right, *why* is it right?**

Comment: Option 2 doesn't mean anything in our current understanding of spacetime. There's no notion of spacetime being thick or thin.

Comment: Hm, in $$\mathrm{d}s^2 = - B \mathrm{d}t^2 + A \mathrm{d}r^2 + r^2 (\mathrm{d}\theta^2 + \sin^2{\theta}\mathrm{d}\phi^2)$$, the $$A$$  can be bigger than 1. The question is: Can it be smaller then 1? Or is the assumption of asymptotical flatness true, can it really *not* be smaller then 1? We were astonished from its capability to become *greater* then 1 with Einstein, about 100 years ago. I simply don't get why it shall not become smaller than 1. That's the meaning of "thinner".

Comment: In principle $A$ can be whatever you want, but in practice it will always look like $1/(1-2M/r)$ as you move away from a mass. By "spacetime vanishes", do you mean that $A$ goes to zero at infinity? I can try to write an answer if you help me clarify your question.

Comment: Yes, that means that A goes to zero at infinity.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming a static spherically symmetric single galaxy universe the metric component $g_{rr}$ as a solution of corresponding Einstein field equations (EFE) reads:

\begin{equation}
g_{rr}=(1-\frac{\kappa c^2}{r}\int_{0}^{r}~\rho(x)~x^2~dx)^{-1} \tag{1}
\end{equation}

As long as the energy density is nonnegative in a space region $r\le R$ the metric component $g_{rr}$ will approach $1$ at the infinity. The only way to achieve $g_{rr}\rightarrow 0$ is to assume that this universe has a negative cosmological constant. The corresponding exterior solution for $g_{rr}$ is (https://arxiv.org/abs/1011.4941, page 20)
\begin{equation}
g^{-1}_{rr}~=~1- \frac{2 G M/c^2}{r}+\Lambda/3~r^2. \tag{2}
\end{equation}

Comment: Thank you very much! Could you please explain in more detail how do you derive equation (1)? $\rho$ is the energy density, I suppose?

Comment: And, please, could you describe *what exactly* is ment with the term "cosmological constant"?

Comment: @BarrierRemoval, please look into https://authors.library.caltech.edu/4362/1/TOLpr39.pdf  and the corresponding differential equation (3.3) for density $\rho$ (energy density is defined as $\rho c^2$). The cosmological constant is the famous Einsteins's $\Lambda$ constant.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 is correct. It seems trivially obvious that when you are infinitely far from something it should no longer affect you, hence spacetime would tend towards flatness.

Option 2 is very vaguely worded and it's not clear what "thinner" means. In a comment you ask about the coefficient in front of the $A dr^2$ term. This will always tend towards $1$ at infinity, because at an infinitely far distance spacetime will tend towards flatness. In turn, this is because the Minkowski metric applies in flat spacetime, and this metric has $A = 1$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Comment: A=1 is surely true for the solar system. But is there some *evidence* that it's also true for galaxies?

Comment: Your approach "being infinitely far means it should not longer affect you" comes from a non-relativistic viewpoint. Now, the spacetime *itself* if affected in general relativity. Therefore it might be reasonable to question the nonrelativistic assumtions.

Comment: Option 2 simply questions the assumtion of asymptotical fatness. Questions whether it could be possible that the nature of spacetime   could be described with a metric with A=0 in the infinity

Comment: @BarrierRemoval *A=1 is surely true for the solar system. But is there some evidence that it's also true for galaxies?* This question makes no sense. Minkowski spacetime applies once there's no matter around. The solar system, the galaxy - they don't matter.

Comment: @BarrierRemoval *Your approach "being infinitely far means it should not longer affect you" comes from a non-relativistic viewpoint. Now, the spacetime itself if affected in general relativity. Therefore it might be reasonable to question the nonrelativistic assumtions.* Definitely not, because even in relativity, the deformations in spacetime decrease with distance. See the Schwarzschild metric as an example and take r -> infinity. It should approach Minkowski spacetime, as it must.

Comment: @BarrierRemoval *Questions whether it could be possible that the nature of spacetime could be described with a metric with A=0 in the infinity* Not possible. $A = 1$ yes, but not $A = 0$. If $A = 0$, it would remove one of the dimensions of space.

Comment: *If A=0, it would remove one of the dimensions of space.* Yes, if it would reach infinity. But in my question it's only the limit value, never reached.